# knitr: can I cite an article in a figure caption using the fig.cap chunk option?

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'd like to cite an article in my figure caption. I've tried using the Rmarkdown/pandoc `[@citekey]` and the latex `\\citep{citekey}` forms in the `fig.cap` chunk option without any luck.

Here is a reproducible example:

````
---
output:
  rmarkdown::tufte_handout
references:
- id: Nobody06
  title: 'My Article'
  author:
  - family: Nobody
    given: Jr
  issued:
    year: 2006
---

Some text [@Nobody06].

```{r figure, fig.cap="A figure [@Nobody06]"}
library(ggplot2)
qplot(1:10, rnorm(10))
```

# References
````

This produces the correct citation in the text block but either `[@Nobody06]` (when I use the RMarkdown form) or `(?)` (when I use the Latex form) in the figure caption.

Here is a screencap: [image: screencap].

Does anyone know if it's possible to use citations in the`fig.cap` field?

Comment: It is not easy at the moment, and I have been working on this problem these days. A mature solution may appear in the next one or two months. If you only care about PDF output, what you could do is perhaps `fig.cap = "A figure \\label{refkey}"`, then `\ref{refkey}`. You may need to run `pdflatex` twice on the LaTeX output. I haven't tested it, though.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'm trying to cite a bibliography reference in the  figure caption, not another figure in the same PDF. Is this what you meant?

Comment: In that case, you can probably put `\\citep{Nobody06}` in the figure caption, but you have to compile the LaTeX document by yourself since Pandoc cannot resolve citations generated by `\cite{}` by default. Or just use the development version of rmarkdown.

Comment: I ran `devtools::install_github('rstudio/rmarkdown')` which installed `rstudio/rmarkdown@eaee966`, but now I get `(?)` in **both** the text block and the figure caption. I see that this is now being rendered as `Some text \citep{Nobody06}.` in the `.tex` file, where it was previously being rendered as `Some text (Nobody 2006)`. I'm also getting a `.bbl` file generated in the directory but it is zero bytes.

Comment: Oh I didn't consider this case of using `references` in YAML. I was only considering using `bibliography` in YAML with a .bib file. In the case of `references`, I don't think there is anything we can do in rmarkdown -- it is totally up to Pandoc whether it can parse and render citations in figure captions. I'm not sure if the .bib approach works, though.

Comment: I tried with a bibliography file too. The result was the same but I only tested `.bibtex` and not `.bib`. Will check latter tomorrow and report. Thanks.

Comment: I get the same problem with `.bib` and `.bibtex` files, and I'm still getting `(?)` with the dev version (`rstudio/rmarkdown@c22ee06`). I've added these details to the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The **bookdown** package extends the functionality of rmarkdown and provides some useful tools. Text-references can be used to address this problem. As described by the package author, text references can be used:

> You can assign some text to a label and reference the text using the
>   label elsewhere in your document.

This works really well with citations, as shown below:

````
---
output: bookdown::tufte_handout2
references:
- id: Nobody06
  title: 'My Article'
  author:
  - family: Nobody
    given: Jr
  issued:
    year: 2006
---


(ref:crossref) Some text [@Nobody06].

```{r figure, fig.cap="(ref:crossref)"}
library(ggplot2)
qplot(1:10, rnorm(10))
```

# References
````

[image]

You'll notice that the output format has been adjusted to `bookdown::tufte_handout2` which allows the bookdown features to work. You can find a full list of the output formats [here](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown/bookdown-output.html).

> Read more about text references here: https://bookdown.org/yihui/bookdown/markdown-extensions-by-bookdown.html#text-references