# how to cite in Rmarkdown chunk caption without using bookdown?

Tags: latex, r-markdown, caption, citations

I am currently doing my thesis in Rmarkdown, and I have some citation I need in figure captions. I found a similar question in [this page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33284343/knitr-can-i-cite-an-article-in-a-figure-caption-using-the-fig-cap-chunk-option), yet the answer refers to the bookdown. In my case, I am using a .bib file.

My issue is that I have the thesis almost all written and the change to bookdown will probably bring errors which will be hard to debug now.

I have in the chunk:

```
{r yPlus, echo=FALSE, fig.cap="\\label{fig:yPlus}Tipo de escoamento dado pela distânica à parede (adaptado de \\cite{Versteeg:2007aa}).", fig.align="center"}
```

but when I run the Rmarkdown, I get [?] in the citation. I have tried `citep` as well, but it raises an error.

Is there a way to work around this issue without many complications? I am not very comfortable with all this yet.

Thank you all for the help.

Comment: You can change to `bookdown` with minimal interruption by using `bookdown::pdf_document2` instead of `pdf_document` as output format. I would give this a try first.

Comment: Thank you, Ralf, for the suggestion. I have tried to perform the change, but it has started raising errors. I am afraid it will not be an easy change.

Comment: Great that you found a solution. Care to add it as an answer instead of comment?

Comment: I have made it figure out what was the problem. For further reference, I was referring to figures in the chunk using `fig.cap="\\label{foo} my caption"`. When I have passed all to the `r foo, fig.cap="my caption"` I made it work. Another issue I found was some of the labels were like `my_foo_label`, so the "_" were bring issues as well. Once again, thank you, @RalfStubner.